# Reading particular part of XML attribute

Tags: xml, grep

I'm trying to get a particular part of an XML attribute. Let's say the XML file is like this:

```
<item>
<title>1000 SMS + 1000 Minuten + 1000 MB</title>
</item>
```

Now I only want to extract the "1000 MB" part. I can get the full line with Grep already, but can't find out how to sed it to remove the remaining text/symbols. I have the following already:

```
grep -o ".* MB" merged.xml
```

Which prints:

```
<title><![CDATA[1000 SMS + 1000 Minuten + 1000 MB
```

Comment: Ok, one step further: grep -o ". MB" merged.xml outputs:

0 MB

Comment: This is a bad approach... what happens if `nnnn MB` occurs in several places and you don't wnat all of them?  Regular expressions are a bad idea for parsing XML.  If you would explain what you're trying to accomplish maybe we can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I'm using datafeeds as affiliate marketeer but the datafeed doesn't specify an attribute: MB.

It is however described in the <title> tag but it is part of a whole sentence. I want to put the '1000 MB' part in my database when parsing the XML.

Comment: So you have two problems.  One is parsing the XML to extract the title.  There's no guarantee the title will be all on one line (could be broken over several lines).  For this, XSLT is the correct tool.  Then, you need to parse the text of the title.  Right now you want to extract the number of MB, but you probably will want to extract other data too, no?  This is a harder problem if you want a solution that can adapt to changing requirements.  Please explain your overall goals in more detail.

Comment: I only need the MB part, the other attributes are provided by actual tags. The name of the attribute (title) will remain the same, this is not dynamic.

Comment: I'm extracting it now like:

$oDOM->loadXML(file_get_contents('merged.xml'));
foreach ($oDOM->getElementsByTagName('item') as $oBookNode)
{
    $sSQL = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO affiliate (provider, prijs, sms, minuten) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($oBookNode->getElementsByTagName('provider')->item(0)->nodeValue),

BTW, this is about the other attributes, not the title one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```sh
$ grep -o '[0-9]* MB' merged.xml
1000 MB
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want, I can go futher now. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this answer was already accepted, so I was discouraged from adding another. And also, the question is badly formulated so it's not really possible to answer; supplying one instance document isn't enough - we have to know what variations in the input one has to handle. I was trying to hint at this.